# Objects within jQuery Wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to examine the properties and methods of objects that I've created with `console.log`. As an example, the object, `hardToFind` below is created within a [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)wrapper `$(function(){});`, but I can't seem to find this object under window, the [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)object, or anywhere else. Can someone help?

```
function easyToFind() {
  console.log("I am easy to find")
}

$(function() {
  //can't find this hardToFind object in console.log(window)!

  var hardToFind = new HardToFind();

  function HardToFind() {
    this.projectName = "New Project";

  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `hardToFind` is a local variable. Outside context can't access the variable. If you want to define a global variable, define it as a property of the `window` object:

```
window.hardToFind = new HardToFind();
```

or remove the `var` keyword.

Comment: The last thing is not recommendable, and I think it will fail in all "old" browsers, say IE9. At least it is bad practice.

Comment: @davidkonrad I don't define (necessary) global variables that way but I haven't read/heard that by dropping the `var` keyword variable will not become a global one in IE9! But, yes,  generally defining _many/unnecessary_ global variables is considered a bad practice.

Comment: OK, IE8 then. My point is that you have to declare the variable, you cannot just "drop" the declaration and _hope_ the browser consider it as a part of the window variable. The browser is more tend to consider the lack of declaration as a lack of declaration in the scope at it is declared.  This is how javascript SHOULD be. Exceptions of that is for convenience, not things you would advice. Not things you would write books about.

Comment: To sum it all up : _you **have** to declare javascript variables, **also** within es6_.

Comment: Well, I haven't said you shouldn't define your variable and I never do this when I'm developing a serious application,  but as far as know all browsers define global variable when the `var` keyword is not used even in IE8.  And no, you don't have to, but yes, not defining variables is a bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Check this example.

```js
// jQuery scope...
$(function() {
  function HardToFind() {
    this.projectName = "New Project"; // Private property.
    this.testMethod = function() // Private method.
      {
        alert(this.projectName); // You can show the projectName property.
      };
  }

  function easyToFind() {
    var hardToFind = new HardToFind();
    hardToFind.projectName = "Another test Project"; // Initializing with other value.
    return hardToFind; // Returning the new value.
  }

  function showAlert() {
    var hardToFind = new HardToFind();
    hardToFind.testMethod(); // hardToFind is instance of the class HardToFind() (OOP). So you can call the private method of the object «hardToFind».
  }

  /* Excuting the methods by default. */
  console.log(easyToFind());
  showAlert(); // Show Alert window, to test private method of HardToFind().
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice, but completely overhead.  We should never code just to get rid of misunderstandings of how a language is meant to be handled.